# Apply flex to all siblings if one siblings needs to flex

Tags: html, css, svg, flexbox, css-grid

Example problem:

- big: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oq0jA.png
- small: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXqmV.png

When there is no enough space, one row starts to flex but others won't if they still have enough space, can I make it so every row flex if at least one has to?

So instead of [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXqmV.png) I want [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeun3.png)

Assets:

- "T": https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6iop.png
- "box with X":

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 510 510"><title>x</title><line x1="5" y1="5" x2="505" y2="505" style="fill:none;stroke:#000;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-width:10px"/><line x1="5" y1="505" x2="505" y2="5" style="fill:none;stroke:#000;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-width:10px"/><rect x="5" y="5" width="500" height="500" style="fill:none;stroke:#000;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-width:10px"/></svg>
```

html:

```
<div className='container'>
  <div className='container__side top'>
    <div className='container__row nameone'>
      <img className='container__type' src='...'/>
      <svg className='container__item' ... />
      // each row have different amount of svg items, because it loop throw array fecthed from api
    </div>
    <div className='container__row nametow'>
    </div>
    // etc
  </div>
  <div className='container__side bottom'>
  </div>
</div>
```

scss:

```
.container {
   background: white;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   padding: 1rem;

   &__row {
     display: flex;
   }

   &__type {
      margin-right: 2rem;
      width: 5rem;
      height: 5rem;
      object-fit: contain;
   }
   &__item {
      padding: .5rem;
      width: 7rem;
      height: 7rem;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add `flex-shrink: 0;` to `&__item`.

You final CSS should look like this:

```
&__item {
    padding: .5rem;
    width: 7rem;
    height: 7rem;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't answer my question, adding shrink 0 will make items overflow and you simply can't see them.

Comment: I know how to do that, but I don't like how it's looks. And that's why I asked this question. I want siblings to flex once one of them starting flexing so all items will be same size.

Comment: We need to use jQuery in order to achieve that. Are we allowed to use jQuery?

Comment: I'm using react for this project, sorry for late reply

Comment: You can remove the flex-shrink. And with javascript you will find the item width from a row which have maximum items and then apply that width to all of the items on the page.